# Arabic input fields in unity

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, arabic, unityscript

Is there is a way to change the language of input fields in unity to Arabic?. I tried ArabicSupport and it displayed Arabic correctly but using it with input fields didn't work because

```
GameObject.Find("input_field")
    .GetComponent<InputField>().text = Fix3dTextCS.fix(   
        GameObject.Find("input_field").GetComponent<InputField>().text
    );
```

caused an error so, if I printed the input text elsewhere, it will appear correctly but how can I do it with the same input field?

Answer (score 1):

input field is a little bit tricky to let it work with Arabic Support

please try this opensource [asset](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/#!/content/108026) it has an prefab for Arabic Input Field and some other UIs.

- OpenSource for ArabicSupport Solution [Link](https://github.com/Konash/arabic-support-unity)
- OpenSource for unity asset UI Arabic Support: [Link](https://github.com/AbdullahAlimam/Arabic-Support-for-Unity-UI)

Comment: Just linking to your own library or tutorial is not a good answer. Linking to it, explaining why it solves the problem, providing code on how to do so and disclaiming that you wrote it makes for a better answer. See: [**What signifies “Good” self promotion?**](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212)

Comment: you are right 
but It's not a very small solution and also my asset is open source they can view the code there and it also depend on another big open source solution

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding arabic font in that input.

If so, post the error message it may help to find the bug

Answer (score -1):

Using Font won't help because it will only change the theme of your current Input usage but not how you use to input in the Device.

You will need to use `Input.Location` <- `Input` is static so you can access it anywhere. The only problem is, I am not sure what is the exact variable for arabic is. My best guess is `Input.Location = "Arabic"` or `"arabic"`.

If you want to automatically detect their location, the GPS which will unity3d turn on by calling `Input.Location.Start`, and turn off by `Input.Location.Stop()`

Here is a sample code for you.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TestLocationService : MonoBehaviour
{
    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        // First, check if user has location service enabled
        if (!Input.location.isEnabledByUser) yield break;

        // Start service before querying location
        Input.location.Start();

        // Wait until service initializes
        int maxWait = 20;
        while (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Initializing && maxWait > 0)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            maxWait--;
        }

        // Service didn't initialize in 20 seconds
        if (maxWait < 1)
        {
            print("Timed out");
            yield break;
        }

        // Connection has failed
        if (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Failed)
        {
            print("Unable to determine device location");
            yield break;
        }
        else
        {
            // Access granted and location value could be retrieved
            print("Location: " + Input.location.lastData.latitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.longitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.altitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.horizontalAccuracy + " " + Input.location.lastData.timestamp);
        }

        // Stop service if there is no need to query location updates continuously
        Input.location.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: How is device location relevant to the question? This isn't even remotely an answer. It starts out like one, then switches to device GPS? The question is about how to get Unity to allow Arabic input.